# How to insert into geometry_columns in postgis 2.0

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

Hello.

When I used postgres 8.4 and postgis 1.5, I register tables (for example, for qgis) with coordinates in geometry_columns.

But now, in postgres 9.2 and postgis 2.0, geometry_columns it's view! And view geometry_columns consists of system tables, which names starts with 'pg_'. How can I insert or update row??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PostGIS management functions, like [`AddGeometryColumn`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html), [`DropGeometryColumn`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/DropGeometryColumn.html), etc.

Alternately, as documented in those pages, you can [manually register columns](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column).